# Never Used Ubuntu Before

Tags: drivers, ati, windows-7, steam

I'm pretty well over windows, and rather than "upgrade" from Win 7 to Win 10, I was thinking about going completely Linux (Ubuntu I presume). Before I do so I plan on dropping Ubuntu onto a spacious thumb-drive and playing with it to learn the ins and outs a bit. However I had a few questions I thought you folks might be able to answer which would help me prepare for the transition.

1. I play games. Can I run Diablo II, Steam, and my AMD Catalyst/Gaming Evolved software in Ubuntu? (Yes, running Diablo II is that important...)
2. Does OpenOffice run well in Ubuntu?
3. How difficult is it to communicate on a home network over a WIFI connection with other devices (Android phone, Windows laptop which is soon to be an Ubuntu machine as well, etc.)?
4. How challenging is it getting all of the hardware drivers for my PC (an HP Pavilion) to work well with the Ubuntu OS?
5. Will my Adobe CS 5.1 Master Collection run on Ubuntu?

The little research I've had time to do on Ubuntu has led me to believe I'd be far happier with it in general than I am with Windows. It seems like once I have some familiarity with the basic suite it's pretty customizable, and many of the encumbrances Windows suffers from (just look at the stuff in the start menu on any Windows machine for an example) are optional (more or less) in Ubuntu if I'm reading things right. I don't expect Ubuntu to be an easy OS to master, but it doesn't seem to difficult to learn to get started, and if I could kiss Windows goodbye, well... that would be fantastic.

Anyways, thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: 1. [Maybe](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=25602). 2. Yes. 3. Communicate how? 4. Maybe. 5. No. I could write a longer answer, but the first *Maybe* is perhaps damning.

Comment: Also, one question (or a set of closely related questions) per post, please.

Comment: Please avoid broad questions and focus on a single issue at a time.

Comment: oops... my bad.

Comment: You currently more or less depend on applications made for Windows, and you probably always will. Microsoft currently offers you their latest product with a 10 year life span for free. Backup your stuff. Get to know the new Windows. Get to know Linux/Ubuntu. Then make your decision which OS you want to run how often and how much of your privacy you are going to give away for services and convenience. Nothing is perfect and everything is in the flow. If you dislike a modern Windows you will probably dislike every other OS at some point in time.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the community! Hopefully I'll be able to help you out with all of your questions.

> 1) I play games. Can I run Diablo II, Steam, and my AMD
>   Catalyst/Gaming Evolved software in Ubuntu? (Yes, running Diablo II is
>   that important...)

Steam most definitely runs on Linux. As for individual steam games, you'll have to check their pages in the store to see if they support Linux. Your AMD catalyst card has supported drivers, you just have to enable them. You should be prompted to do so during setup, which is as easy as just clicking on them and hitting okay.

Diablo II isn't available on Steam last I checked, but there is software called Wine. Wine will help you run Windows executables on Ubuntu, and according to their app database [Diablo II works fantastically](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=74).

> 2) Does OpenOffice run well in Ubuntu?

In my opinion, OpenOffice runs BETTER in Ubuntu. However, Ubuntu does come preinstalled with the successor of OpenOffice called LibreOffice. LibreOffice has all of the same functionality and more, and supports all OpenOffice formats. Not surprising, because it was created by the OpenOffice team. Give it a shot first! I think you'll like it a lot.

> 3) How difficult is it to communicate on a home network over a WIFI
>   connection with other devices (Android phone, Windows laptop which is
>   soon to be an Ubuntu machine as well, etc.)?

It's really not difficult at all. It's infinitely easier to communicate with an Android phone than an iPhone (trust me, months of futzing with an iPhone I was stuck with taught me my lesson). But you definitely shouldn't have any issues with getting in touch with your devices over WiFi at all, that is built in functionality that you should see in the menu while browsing your files.

> 4) How challenging is it getting all of the hardware drivers for my PC
>   (an HP Pavilion) to work well with the Ubuntu OS?

Generally speaking, most computers work with Ubuntu out of the box. HP especially, because Canonical (the company that heavily supports Ubuntu) works closely with HP to make sure it works. You can always check [this page](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/make/HP/) to see if yours is certified to work, but in my experience it's easily possible to get Ubuntu to work on just about anything.

> 5) Will my Adobe CS 5.1 Master Collection run on Ubuntu?

This is a tough question. Some pieces of CS5 run under wine, others do not. I would search for them in the [Wine App Database](https://appdb.winehq.org/). I would also ask around here or the forums to see if there are any suitable alternatives to you - I transitioned away from the Adobe suite long before I left Windows for good and I've never looked back. GIMP is a very solid graphics editing program available for every platform, and is one of Photoshop's biggest competitors. If you can't get something to work, there are always open source alternatives.

I hope you enjoy Ubuntu! Let me know how everything goes.

Now the boring stuff:

On AskUbuntu they typically prefer that you focus on one question per post. Try to make sure you do that from now on! If you have a whole bunch of questions about a specific or general topic, it may be faster for you just to post them all at once in one thread on the [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/).

Comment: Here's the actual link to Diablo 2 in the winehq database: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=74

Comment: Thanks, Mark, and sorry about the faux-pas. Your answers were very informative! Being new to the Ubuntu community I had no idea where to post a question like this, and being pressed for time I just took a chance someone would be helpful. You were very much so, and I appreciate your time.